# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error while connection between mule and snowflake

Tags: mule, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, anypoint-studio

I am creating a new flow in mule 3.9 using http connector and gerenic data base connector to connect to snowflake to run a procedure.

There are no error in the code,i could see that the codeis running successfully but i am getting
the below error.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I have updated the anypoint.ini file upgraded the memory to 10240 still it didnt work

i am using snowflake jar 3.13.3 for this project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cdata-snowflake="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cdata-snowflake" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cdata-snowflake http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cdata-snowflake/current/mule-cdata-snowflake.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call E2e_Change_User('nudayaku' ,'tan')]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:stored-procedure>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

i have tried but parameterized query as well as dynamic  way , but both were resulting in timout error.

I have run the same procedure from snowflake , i am getting the output in seconds.

Can some help me how to fix the issue

Appreciate inputs

Thanks,
Sidh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue in Mule 3.9.0 to Mule 3.9.4. The solution is to upgrade to Mule 3.9.5.

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Store-procedure-calls-fail-in-mule-3-x-for-snowflake-database